# Conflict between pydantic constr and mypy checking

Tags: python, mypy, pydantic

I'm using pydantic to validate a Json/Dict input. But I'm also using mypy to validate the type integrity of the code.

When using the `pydantic.constr` type, which, among other things, validates if a given string respects a regex, I get a mypy error.

Here is the code:

```
from typing import List

import pydantic

Regex = pydantic.constr(regex="[0-9a-z_]*")


class Data(pydantic.BaseModel):
    regex: List[Regex]


data = Data(**{"regex":["abc", "123", "etc"]})
print(data, data.json())
```

And here is the mypy output:

```
$ mypy main.py 
main.py:9: error: Variable "main.Regex" is not valid as a type
main.py:9: note: See https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/common_issues.html#variables-vs-type-aliases
```

I checked the documentation, but could not find a way to handle this. I know I could create a static type for that regex, but that kind of defeats the purpose of pydantic. The only way I could make this pass was with a `# type: ignore` which is far from ideal.

So is there a way of handling this in a way to have both the pydantic and mypy benefits?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are a few ways to achieve this:

### Inheriting from `pydantic.ConstrainedStr`

Instead of using `constr` to specify the regex constraint (which uses `pydantic.ConstrainedStr` internally), you can inherit from `pydantic.ConstrainedStr` directly:

```
import re
import pydantic
from pydantic import Field
from typing import List

class Regex(pydantic.ConstrainedStr):
    regex = re.compile("^[0-9a-z_]*$")

class Data(pydantic.BaseModel):
    regex: List[Regex]

data = Data(**{"regex": ["abc", "123", "asdf"]})
print(data)
# regex=['abc', '123', 'asdf']
print(data.json())
# {"regex": ["abc", "123", "asdf"]}
```

Mypy accepts this happily and pydantic does correct validation. The type of `data.regex[i]` is `Regex`, but as `pydantic.ConstrainedStr` itself inherits from `str`, it can be used as a string in most places.

### Using `pydantic.Field`

The regex consraint can also be specified as an argument to [`Field`](https://pydantic-docs.helpmanual.io/usage/schema/#field-customisation):

```
import pydantic
from pydantic import Field
from typing import List

class Regex(pydantic.BaseModel):
    __root__: str = Field(regex="^[0-9a-z_]*$")

class Data(pydantic.BaseModel):
    regex: List[Regex]

data = Data(**{"regex": ["abc", "123", "asdf"]})
print(data)
# regex=[Regex(__root__='abc'), Regex(__root__='123'), Regex(__root__='asdf')]
print(data.json())
# {"regex": ["abc", "123", "asdf"]}
```

Because `Regex` is not directly used as a field in a pydantic model (but as an entry in a list in your example), we need to introduce a model by force. `__root__` makes the `Regex` model act as its single field when validating and serializing (more details [here](https://pydantic-docs.helpmanual.io/usage/models/#custom-root-types)).

But it has a drawback: the type of `data.regex[i]` is again `Regex`, but this time not inheriting from `str`. This results in e.g. `foo: str = data.regex[0]` not typechecking. `foo: str = data.regex[0].__root__` has to be used instead.

I'm still mentioning this here because it might be the simplest solution when the constraint is applied directly to a field and not to a list entry (and `typing.Annotated` is not avaible, see below). For example like so:

```
class DataNotList(pydantic.BaseModel):
    regex: str = Field(regex="^[0-9a-z_]*$")
```

### Using `typing.Annotated` with `pydantic.Field`

Instead of using `constr` to specify the regex constraint, you can specify it as an argument to [`Field`](https://pydantic-docs.helpmanual.io/usage/schema/#field-customisation) and then use it in combination with `typing.Annotated`:

```
import pydantic
from pydantic import Field
from typing import Annotated

Regex = Annotated[str, Field(regex="^[0-9a-z_]*$")]

class DataNotList(pydantic.BaseModel):
    regex: Regex

data = DataNotList(**{"regex": "abc"})
print(data)
# regex='abc'
print(data.json())
# {"regex": "abc"}
```

Mypy treats `Annotated[str, Field(regex="^[0-9a-z_]*$")]` as a type alias of `str`. But it also tells pydantic to do validation.
This is described in the pydantic docs [here](https://pydantic-docs.helpmanual.io/usage/schema/#typingannotated-fields).

Unfortunately it does not curretly work with the following:

```
class Data(pydantic.BaseModel):
    regex: List[Regex]
```

The validation simply does not get run. This is an open bug ([github issue](https://github.com/samuelcolvin/pydantic/issues/2551#issuecomment-803527185)). Once the bug is fixed this might overall be the best solution.

Note that `typing.Annotated` is only available since Python 3.9. For older Python versions [`typing_extensions.Annotated`](https://pypi.org/project/typing-extensions/) can be used.

---

As a side note: I've used `^[0-9a-z_]*$` instead of `[0-9a-z_]*` for the regex, as the latter would accept *any* string as valid, as [pydantic uses `re.match` for validation](https://github.com/samuelcolvin/pydantic/issues/1631).